# Progress bar working in all browser except IE (Angular + bootstrap)

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, progress-bar

I am using Angular and bootstrap to show a progress bar. here is the html

```
<div class="progress progress-striped  active ">
    <div class="bar bar-info" style="width:{{score}}%"></div>
</div>
```

`score` is coming from my controller. This code works in all the browser except IE.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is it doing in Internet Explorer? Which version of Internet Explorer? Is there any relevant output in the console (Press F12)?

Comment: Worth nothing that Angular ships with expectations of [IE-related issues](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

Comment: IE version 10.Nothing happens in IE, no message on console, It shows the progress bar without the progress. Looks like it simply does not parse {{score}}. However, I have similar line like ng-hide= {{loginVisible}} is working. even style="visibility:{{showSearch}}" is working on the same page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular UI Bootstrap progress bar in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184637/angular-ui-bootstrap-progress-bar-in-ie10)

Answer (score 13):

Just change to the following:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped  active ">
    <div class="bar bar-info" ng-attr-style="width:{{score}}%;"></div>
</div>
```

When you want to use Angular interpolation in an HTML attribute like style you need to use the `ng-attr-` prefix for that attribute for it to place nice in the browser.

Comment: ng-attr-style="width:{{score}}%;" instead of style="width:{{score}}%"

Answer (score 7):

If your "score" is getting the value properly then apply the style little differently, The code below worked for me:

Change your style attribute to ng-style="width={width:'{{ score}}%'}"

```
<div class="progress progress-striped  active ">
    <div class="bar bar-info" ng-style="width={width:'{{ score}}%'}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I love Internet Explorer so much </sarcasm>

Answer (score 5):

Found the workaround from [theDemi post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184637/angular-ui-bootstrap-progress-bar-in-ie10/17384084#17384084). You have to write your own directive as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myProgress', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(attrs.myProgress, function(val) {
       element.html('<div class="bar" style="width: ' + val + '%"></div>');
  });
 }
});
```

usage:

```
 <div class="progress" my-progress="nameOfYourProgressModelVariable"></div>
```

Comment: This works great so far.  Please note that in the attribute value, `nameOfYourProgressModelVariable` is only the name of the variable, not the value - so leave off the curly braces.  It works exactly as shown.